# I'm on the fence about closing this question for the reason "too broad"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close

The following question is under review for being closed as too broad.

Here's the question: [Coffee on daily basis](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/coffee-on-daily-basis)

I would like to know what the community thinks about this. **Is it too broad, or not?**

Also this question has a poor format in my opinion. Here is how I believe it should be structured:

1. Ask if coffee on a daily basis is healthy or not.
2. Based on that result, ask why or why not it is healthy or unhealthy.

(Which still may be quite broad)

I am interested to know the community's opinion on this.

Comment: For some (e.g. those who metabolize caffeine slowly), daily cups of coffee may well interfere with routine sleep.  Those of us who don't have that problem, and who consume coffee (in multiple cups) on a daily basis, will tend to see our experience as normative (among coffee drinkers).  So I think the Question was poorly posed.  "Too broad" is one way of looking at it, but it might have been better to draw the OP out for some clarification (narrowing/context) before those who did launched into attempting to answer.